# Como recebo dados (números int.) de outra activity?

Tags: java, android

**Eu pesquisei diversos posts aqui no stackoverflow e** não encontrei nenhum falando sobre migrar números inteiros, **tentei diversas coisas mas não deu certo**. Sou iniciante e provavelmente deixei passar algo bobo, mas não consigo ver o que é.

Eu estou montando um quiz, com diversas activitys e queria fazer um score que fosse somando 1 ponto por cada questão certa de cada activity.

Segue meu código que não está funcionando. Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico grato desde já.

Activity 1

```js
public class A_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView score;
int mScore = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_activity);

    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

}

public void onClickTrue(View v) {
    mScore++;
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, B_Activity.class);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putInt("mScore", mScore);
    i.putExtras(params);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Activity 2 (recepção)

```js
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b_activity);

    Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null){
            Bundle params = i.getExtras();

            if (params != null){
                String mScore = params.getString("mScore");

                }

        }

}
```

Comment: Se o que passou no intent foi um int com `params.putInt()` então na outra Activity tem de usar `params.getInt()`.

Comment: @ramaral, obrigado pelo feedback, mas mesmo tentando o que você falou e os posts que estão sinalizados como dublicados não está funcionando.

Comment: Eu já respondi à pergunta no primeiro comentário, não sei o que mais possa dizer. Na resposta aceite da pergunta indicada tem um exemplo de como passar um inteiro.